# Trying to improve performance of generating xls reports using DynamicJasper. Any suggestions in this direction?

Tags: java, reporting, xls, dynamic-jasper

**Current stats:**

Generating a .xls file containing 3 tables, each of one containing 100K rows x 3 columns took ~24s with the following breakdown:

- building the JRXlsExporter - ~6s
- JRXlsExporter.exportReport() - ~18s

The code was executed on the following hardware: i7 6core CPU, 16GB RAM, SSD storage. The maximum heap size for the JVM was set to 4GB.

Adding a snippet just to give you some insight on how I'm adding multiple tables. I'm using in-memory datasources for populating the tables.

```java
DynamicReportBuilder drb = new DynamicReportBuilder();
...
DynamicReport subReport = this.createSubreport(report.getSubReports()[i]);
String dsName = String.valueOf(i);
drb.addConcatenatedReport(subReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(),
                    dsName, DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_ORIGIN_PARAMETER,
                    DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_COLLECTION, false);
...
```

**DynamicJasper version:**

- dynamicjasper: **5.1.0**
- jasperreports: **6.3.0**
- dynamicjasper core fonts: **1.0**

**So far tried the following options:**

- played with virtualization: **no virtualization**, **JRSwapFileVirtualizer**, **JRGzipVirtualizer** and **JRFileVirtualizer**. Best times have been registered using **JRSwapFileVirtualizer** (this is the one used for the provided stats)
- tried changing **net.sf.jasperreports.text.measurer.factory** with **com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.SingleLineTextMeasurerFactory** [1] but wasn't able to find any source code for **SingleLineTextMeasurerFactory** .

[1] https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-modify-jasperreportsproperties-file-disable-multi-line-data-processing

Comment: Did you try without xls, to see whether csv/html/xlsx export makes any change? Are the queries slow? In one sentence: split up the problem.

Comment: The query times are not included in the stats. The times I've provided are spent solely on building the dynamic report and on rendering (all the data is already available in-memory when this process starts). So I've excluded the query times. I'll try to see what impact does the format have on the performance. However, *.xls is the required format and I was wondering if there are any specific xls API known issues.

Comment: Cell references and the sharing of cell values can surprise. Everything with a DOM should be checked. In separate apps writing csv and reading csv and writing xls/xlsx should be worthwile. It helped me on occasion, together with profiling. Last time it was a cell reference.